# SVN still asking to commit ignored files

Tags: svn, svnignore

I ran `svn propedit svn:ignore directory_x .`

When I run `svn pg -R svn:ignore .` I see the **directory_x** inside the ignored list

However, after I do `svn status`, I can still see the directory and it always asks me to commit the same directory.

I tried to run svn cleanup but nothing changed

Comment: Was `directory_x` (or any of its contents) previously added (IOW, does it exist in the repository)?

Comment: @alroc it does exist in the repository but I don't want to commit it

Comment: What is the output of `svn pg -R svn:ignore`?

Comment: @steffen the output is . - directory_x

Comment: If it's in the repository, it's already been committed. Are you conflating repository & working copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `svn:ignore` only affects files that are not in the repository. See [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html):

> Once an object is under Subversion's control, the ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it. In other words, don't expect Subversion to avoid committing changes you've made to a versioned file simply because that file's name matches an ignore pattern—Subversion always notices all of its versioned objects.

And

> `svn:ignore`
>
> If present on a directory, the value is a list of *unversioned* file patterns to be ignored by svn status and other subcommands. See the section called "Ignoring Unversioned Items".